# Android How do I get text type file's name and path from local device?

Tags: android, android-intent, path

```
search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.FindButton);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });
```

I used ACTION_GET_CONTENT function to get file's name and local path.(setType is */* but I want to get json file)

so this is my onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 1){

    }
}
```

When I choose data and then what code do I put in there?

Answer (score 0):

> I used ACTION_GET_CONTENT function to get file's name and local path

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has nothing to do with files.

> When I choose data and then what code do I put in there?

You are welcome to use a `ContentResolver` to `query()` for the `OpenableColumns`, which can give you a "display name". That is not necessarily a filename, because you are working with content, not files. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/Documents) for getting the `OpenableColumns` using a `CursorLoader`.

However, you cannot get a "file path", as this is not a file. It is content. What you are asking is akin to asking how to get the file path for `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878541/android-how-do-i-get-text-type-files-name-and-path-from-local-device`.

You can use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Decent JSON parsers (e.g., Gson) accept an `InputStream` and can parse the JSON from there.